# Java using https to connect elasticsearch cluster

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I installed search guard for the elasticsearch cluster. Now I need to use the account password to connect to the cluster and use the https method, but according to my code, after the startup, the query operation will give an error, the code is as follows

I will get an error when I use the code below.

```
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

@Bean
public static RestHighLevelClient getInstance() {
    String esAuth = "Basic " + Base64.encode(user + ":" + password);
    Header[] defaultHeaders = new Header[]{new BasicHeader("Authorization", esAuth)};
    client = new RestHighLevelClient(
            RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(ip, port, "https"))
                    .setDefaultHeaders(defaultHeaders)
                    .setMaxRetryTimeoutMillis(150000)
                    .setRequestConfigCallback(requestConfigBuilder -> requestConfigBuilder
                            .setConnectTimeout(5000)
                            .setSocketTimeout(150000)));
    return client;
}
```

This is an error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request cannot be executed; I/O
 reactor status: STOPPED    at
 org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(Asserts.java:46)
 ~[httpcore-4.4.10.jar:4.4.10]  at
 org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.ensureRunning(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:90)
 ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.4.jar:4.1.4]     at
 org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient.execute(InternalHttpAsyncClient.java:123)
 ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.4.jar:4.1.4]     at
 org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequestAsync(RestClient.java:529)
 ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-6.4.3.jar:6.5.4]   at
 org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequestAsyncNoCatch(RestClient.java:514)
 ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-6.4.3.jar:6.5.4]   at
 org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:226)
 ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-6.4.3.jar:6.5.4]   at
 org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1593)
 ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
```

Comment: I assume you could do the same request when guard is disabled, right?

Comment: Yes, the query is ok before I install search guard